# Add validation and error message if empty params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to validate whether or not a Credit has been assigned to a Track in a form. The track is saving, the `errors.add` isn't working.
Ideas?

```
class Track
  has_many :credits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credits, allow_destroy: true
  attr_accessible :credits_attributes

  has_many :vendors, through: :credits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vendors
  attr_accessible :vendor_ids
end
```

And trying to validate that the Credit bit of the form is filled out on a Track edit page:

```
def verify_credits
  @track = Track.find(params[:id])
  if !params.has_key?(:split) || params[:track][:credits_attributes][:vendor_id].empty? 
    puts '*' * 300
    @track.errors.add(:base, 'You must credit this track to a Vendor with a split')
  end
end
```

and I call `verify_credits` in overwritten contoller actions in ActiveAdmin track.rb. The puts '*' is coming through so I know my conditional is fine. Example:

```
def update

  referrer = params[:track][:referrer]
  params[:track].delete(:referrer)

  s3_path = params[:track][:file_cache] if params[:track][:file_cache]
  params[:track].delete(:file_cache) unless s3_path.empty?

  @track = Track.find(params[:id])
  @track.assign_attributes(params[:exclusivities])
  verify_credits
  authorize! :update, @track
  if s3_path
    Delayed::Job.enqueue ProcessTrackFileJob.new(@track.id, s3_path) unless s3_path.empty?
  end
  super do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to referrer } unless referrer.to_s.empty?
  end
end
```

> ADDED:

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= f.inputs "Vendors" do %>
      <% f.has_many :credits do |c|%>
        <% c.input :vendor, as: :string, required: true, input_html: { %>
          <% class: 'autocomplete', %>
          <% name: '', %>
          <% value: c.object.vendor.try(:name), %>
          <% data: { %>
            <% url: autocomplete_manage_vendors_path %>
          <% } %>
        <% } %>
        <% c.input :vendor_id, as: :hidden %>
        <% c.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, required: false, label: "Remove" %>
        <% c.input :split %>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any validations in your `Track` model. If you're trying to make sure there is a `vendor_id`, you would need `validates :vendor_id, presence: true` in your `Track` model. If not, your `Track` model doesn't know there is an error if `vendor_id` is missing.

Comment: Thanks. Adding that to my track model doesn't work. It causes it to not save whether I fill out Credit form fields or not.

Comment: You could do a conditional validation in that case. You would want to do the validation only if someone fills out the Credit form fields (if I'm understanding you correctly). I'm assuming those fields are in your `attr_accessible :credits_attributes`.   

If that's the case, something like this should work `validates :vendor_id, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |track| track.credits_attributes.present? }`. If it's not under `:credits_attributes`, just change what I wrote for where those fields are stored.